# Playn error - org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error

Tags: java, lwjgl, playn, x11

After much work around, now i am able to understand the playn environment. Every thing is ok now, but, when i enter:

mvn install (from the main directory)
(or)
mvn java/pom.xml test -Ptest-java

I am getting the following error. I updated the pom.xml (java directory) with this

```
<!-- unpack LWJGL when testing -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.mavennatives</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-nativedependencies-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpacknatives</id>
        <phase>test-compile</phase>
        <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Then also, same error, can any one guide me on this

```
    main:
 [java] failed to create drawable
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0xa0b7cc8 serial: 91 error: BadGC (invalid GC parameter) request_code: 60 minor_code: 0
 [java]     at playn.java.JavaGLContext.initGL(JavaGLContext.java:183)
 [java]     at playn.java.JavaGraphics.init(JavaGraphics.java:155)
 [java]     at playn.java.JavaPlatform.run(JavaPlatform.java:218)
 [java]     at playn.core.PlayN.run(PlayN.java:37)
 [java]     at main.java.ExampleJava.main(ExampleJava.java:13)
 [java] Caused by: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: X Error - disp: 0xa0b7cc8 serial: 91 error: BadGC (invalid GC parameter) request_code: 60 minor_code: 0
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.globalErrorHandler(LinuxDisplay.java:316)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxKeyboard.nSetDetectableKeyRepeat(Native Method)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxKeyboard.setDetectableKeyRepeat(LinuxKeyboard.java:152)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxKeyboard.destroy(LinuxKeyboard.java:163)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.destroyKeyboard(LinuxDisplay.java:1190)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard.destroy(Keyboard.java:349)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.destroyWindow(Display.java:349)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.access$400(Display.java:62)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display$5.destroy(Display.java:860)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:880)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:782)
 [java]     at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:764)
 [java]     at playn.java.JavaGLContext.initGL(JavaGLContext.java:173)
 [java]     ... 4 more
 [java] Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fact: Linux 64-bit + LWJGL = Problems

If you are using a 64-bit Linux then try these one by one:

- Upgrade to the newest version of LWJGL(2.8.4)
- Install OpenJDK7 64-bit and have it as the default jvm
- I believe there was a third fix but forgot what it was. I'll edit it in when I find it.

If you're using a 32-bit Linux then none of these will help.